# how to create a shortcode from a variable in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, posts, wp-query, variables

im using WP User Frontend Pro plugin
i want to echo the pack title using a shortcode to put it in bakery visual
all what i know is this is the title $pack->post_title;

i tried something like this

```
function wpc_shortcode_pack_title() {
global $pack;
echo $pack->post_title;
}
add_shortcode( 'sub_name', 'wpc_shortcode_pack_title' );
```

but didnt work.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about `didn't work`? Did you mean the value is not available? Or did you mean when you add the shortcode, nothing is displayed? Or anything else?

Comment: What is a "pack"?